# Function doesn´t work with more parameters

Tags: php, pdo, count, prepared-statement

This is my function:

```
    function countRows($sql, $parameters){

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms","root");

    $result = $db->prepare($sql); 

    foreach ($parameters as $key => $parameter) {
            $result->bindParam($key, $parameter);
    }

    $result->execute(); 
    $number_of_rows = $result->fetchAll();

    return count($number_of_rows);
}
```

With $parameters array like this it works just fine:

```
$parameters=array("key"=>"parameter");
```

But when the array has more keys and variables it just will give result 0

For example with array like this it gives me 0 rows, when it should be 3

```
 $parameters=array("key"=>"parameter", "key2"=>"parameter2");
```

Edit:

Example of an query:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password"
```

Example of an $parameters for this query:

```
$parameters = array(":username"=>$username, ":password"=>$password);
```

When i run it with one column (like only username or only password) it runs fine, with both it returns always 0.

Comment: Where is your query?

Comment: $result prepares SQL command, then foreach loop binds parameters and then it executes.

Comment: Please add example of query and maybe table as well with sqlfiddle

Comment: Added an example of query and array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `bindParam()` for a variable that changes its value:

```
foreach ($parameters as $key => $parameter) {
        $result->bindParam($key, $parameter);
}
```

You have to understand that `bindParam()` binds the *variable* by reference, not the value the variable has at the time you do the bind.

You're binding the variable `$parameter` to both parameters in your query. The value isn't sent until you call `execute()`. So it sends the value that the variable has after the loop is finished, which is the password.

I tested this by enabling the general query log on my MySQL server, and observing what gets logged:

```
140905 10:09:45    49 Connect   root@192.168.56.1 on test
           49 Prepare   SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?
           49 Execute   SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='password' AND password='password'
           49 Close stmt    
           49 Quit
```

You can solve this in either of two ways:

- Use `bindValue()` instead of `bindParam()`. This copies the value of `$parameter` at the time you do the bind.
- Alternatively, you don't need to do a loop for binding parameters one at a time all, just pass the array to `execute()`:

  ```
  $result->execute($parameters);
  ```

I don't know why so many developers believe they're required to write code to bind parameters one at a time. It's easier to pass the array of parameters directly to `execute()`.

Comment: Well, but i use all of my parameters in my query. When i try to print out errorInfo() from my $result variable, i don´t get anything.

Comment: There is SQL statement included. And when i try to use less parameters than i have binded i get the same error as you.

Comment: @WannaBeGnome, I have updated my answer significantly.

Comment: Thanks, when I deleted foreach loop and put $parameters into execute(), it started to work. I was using bindParam just because I think it is more clear when i bind it instead of just writing it into execute().

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters should look like array

```
$parameters = [
 "key"   =>  "parameter",
 "key2 " =>  "parameter2"
];
```

Then You missed the password

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms","root","your_password");
```

My idea take a look on [PDOStatement::bindParam Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Comment: I didn´t get what you said. My $parameters is array. And my database doesn´t have a password, its on localhost, connection is fine.

Comment: @WannaBeGnome Please add this line $db->debugDumpParams(); before return

Comment: got this Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::debugDumpParams() in C:\xampp\htdocs\TryTHis\include\db.php on line 23